# Ajax address bar variable issue

Tags: ajax, variables, share

I have a site that places a variables into the address bar.

www.mywebsite.com/index.php?user=288

I simply use `usernum = $_GET["user"];` to assign the variable.

I can use this variable no problem, but when it comes to the ajax within that page getting the variable - it just won't acknowledge it.

How can I get ajax to get the address bar variable too?

----NEW CONTENT--

I'm new to ajax so don't be harsh

```
function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("centreCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","../profile/" + pageName + ".php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

Comment: What have you written in terms of ajax so far?

Comment: Post the ajax code, please. Click "edit" and copy/paste it to your post.

Comment: OK, i've added ajax code. Looking through various posts it looks like I might have to make the variable javascript and not PHP or something? Or make it global? - I'm not javascript savvy!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use the following:

```
var qs = window.location.search;
xmlhttp.open("GET","../profile/" + pageName + ".php" + qs,true);
```

qs contains the query string for your current page's URL. So this will append all your current page's query string to your AJAX page's request.